# retrieve the second line of a text box in a Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Dears, 
I’m trying to retrieve the second line of a text box in a Worksheet,

Ex:
Blue
Mika Ralf
23.05

I would like to copy the name and use it in some other parts of my macro
The Text Box was created with Insert  Text Box 
And the name is TextBox 17
Thank you very much for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up whether your TextBox is an ActiveX control or a Form control:

from its name ("TextBox 17" has a space in it) I'd say it's a Form control

anyhow here is code for both possibilities

---

**Solution for Form control**

```
Function GetStringFromTextBox_Form(textBoxName As String, strngPos As Integer) As String    
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(textBoxName).TextFrame.Characters
       GetStringFromTextBox_Form = Split(.Text, "")(strngPos - 1)
    End With    
End Function
```

to be used like follows

```
Sub main()
    Dim name As String        

    name = GetStringFromTextBox_Form("TextBox 17", 2) '<~~ use this if your TextBox is a Form Control        
    MsgBox name
End Sub
```

---

**Solution for ActiveX control**

```
Function GetStringFromTextBox_ActiveX(textBoxName As String, strngPos As Integer) As String
    With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(textBoxName).Object
        GetStringFromTextBox_ActiveX = Split(.Text, vbCrLf)(strngPos - 1)
    End With
End Function
```

to be used like follows

```
Sub main()
    Dim name As String

    name = GetStringFromTextBox_ActiveX("TextBox17", 2) '<~~ use this if your TextBox is an Active X Control        
    MsgBox name
End Sub
```

Comment: works well!! I think your '<~~ are wrong... but the rest is awesome thanks

Comment: @gizlmeier actually wrote a working solution first, so give credits to him. you may up-vote my solution if you find it useful.    BTW I edited the `<~~...` comments right after posting my answer. may be you read it while they were still mixed up

Answer (score 1):

Use `Split` to get all lines of a textbox into an array:

```
Dim lines() As String

'Split lines of the textbox into array and remove line breaks
lines = Split(Replace(Me.txtTest.Value, Chr(13), ""), Chr(10))

'print line 2
Debug.Print lines(1)
```

Or if you really just need the second line:

```
Debug.Print Split(Replace(Me.txtTest.Value, Chr(13), ""), Chr(10))(1)
```

Here you are directly accessing the second element of the Split function (which is like an array)

Replace `Me.txtTest` with the name of your Textbox.

Comment: thank you, looks good ! I think this works with userforms. I would need something for a shapes textbox...

Comment: If it is a Shapes Textbox, it is a little trickier to get it's value in VBA:
`Sheets("SHEETNAME").Shapes.Range(Array("SHAPENAME")).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.text` Enter the right Sheetname and name of the shape and place this code instead of `Me.txtTest.Value`

Comment: @gizlmeier I was writing my post while you added your last comment to yours, but you first!. Just a little longer mine for ActiveX control (I could use `ActiveSheet.TextBox17.Text`) and a little longer yours for Form control (you could avoid most of the `Range(Array("SHAPENAME")).TextFrame2.TextRange` part)

Comment: There sure is a better way to get the value than i did it. but this was the only way i knew